# Why doesn't Xcode recognized Cosine?

Tags: xcode, trigonometry

(posted imports)

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>          //must be included for OpenGL
#include <Opengl/gl.h>              //must be included for OpenGL
#include <math.h>

#include <time.h>           //must be included for time functions
#include <iostream>         //must be included for console input/output
#include <fstream>


void ShowMapCircle2()

float radius =300;
float theta = 0;

for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(radius*cos(theta), radius*sin(theta),0);

    glTranslated(360,250,0);
    glRotated(-90+i*30,0,0,1);
    glTranslated(-360,-250,0);

    glTranslated(360,250,0);
    glScaled(0.4,0.4,1);
    glTranslated(-360,-250,0);

    ShowUSMAP();
    glPopMatrix();

    theta += 30*3.14159/180;
}
```

}

Cos is not recognized by Xcode.  I don't know what's going on. I get "use of undeclared identifier 'cos' ." I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't figure it out. 'cos' seems to want to be defined in xcode?

```
glTranslated(radius*cos(theta), radius*sin(theta),0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to include the math header?

```
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: Spinning beachball of death now.